# when in try to access mysql view using django model it throws an error

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I want to access the records in mysql view using django filter but it throws an error

```
class PartnerPayBillSummaryDetails(models.Model):
    invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    invoice_id = models.IntegerField()
    partner_id = models.IntegerField()
    partner_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=50)
    invoice_date = models.DateField()
    bill_received_date = models.DateField()
    due_date = models.DateField()
    due_date_ageing = models.IntegerField()
    payable_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '66_1_partner_pay_bill_ageing_dtl'
```

```
try:
    p = PartnerPayBillSummaryDetails.objects.all()
    print(p)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Error:

```
OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column '66_1_partner_pay_bill_ageing_dtl.id' in 'field list'")
```

Comment: Can you please share your `PartnerPayBillSummaryDetails` model and all relevant ones?

Comment: I created a view in DB, and then I replicate the view in django model

Comment: I'm assuming that table with that name is already in the database and that table has a field called 'id'. Am I right?

Comment: yes, I created it using MySQL query then I replicate it in django without affecting migration files by add managed = False

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer

> it requires a filed as a primary key. I solve this by adding
>   "primary_key=True" in invoice_id

```
invoice_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is looking for a primary key called 'id' (by default if you don't define). Also your db_table name in meta class is starting with a number. Not sure it will allow that. I am away from computer to test it out but based on guess, I have two solutions for you. Please try them in that order. All I have done is change your model class in both the solutions.

```py
class PartnerPayBillSummaryDetails(models.Model):
    invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    invoice_id = models.IntegerField()
    partner_id = models.IntegerField()
    partner_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=50)
    invoice_date = models.DateField()
    bill_received_date = models.DateField()
    due_date = models.DateField()
    due_date_ageing = models.IntegerField()
    payable_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'partner_pay_bill_ageing_dtl_66_1'
```

Solution 2

```py
class PartnerPayBillSummaryDetails(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    invoice_id = models.IntegerField()
    partner_id = models.IntegerField()
    partner_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=50)
    invoice_date = models.DateField()
    bill_received_date = models.DateField()
    due_date = models.DateField()
    due_date_ageing = models.IntegerField()
    payable_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'partner_pay_bill_ageing_dtl_66_1'
```

Please let me know if there is still some error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add primary key to the model.

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

or make any column the primary key like:

```
invoice_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```